# obtaining empirical CDF of a given data

Tags: python, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have a dataset of variable $x$ that has a value between 0 and 6. I would like to have a function that defines empirical CDF of variable $x$. Since $x$ does not have a specific distribution (such as Gaussian, etc.), I need to rely on data values to create this function. Using the following code, I can plot the empirical CDF as:

```
max_diam = 6
ax = sns.distplot(x, hist_kws=dict(cumulative=True), kde_kws=dict(cumulative=True)).set(xlim=(0, max_diam))
ax = sns.kdeplot(x, bw=.1, cumulative=True).set(xlim=(0, max_diam), ylim=(0, 1.0))#, color="r")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I would like to find the function that `kdeplot` uses to plot CDF. I have tried to do regression, but the quality is not good, as there is only a single point after 4.9 (6.0) which makes the plot overfit for high orders and underfit in low orders

```
def ecdf(data):
    # Compute ECDF
    x = np.sort(data)
    n = x.size
    y = np.arange(1, n+1) / n
    return(x,y)

x, y = ecdf(x)
degree=7
lw = 2

plt.scatter(x=x, y=y, s=10);
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=16)

polynomial_features= PolynomialFeatures(degree)
x_poly = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x.reshape(-1, 1))

model = skl.LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, y)

x_test = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x_plot.reshape(-1, 1))
y_test = model.predict(x_test)
plt.plot(x_plot, y_test, color='yellowgreen', linewidth=lw, label="degree %d" % degree)

plt.show()
```

[image]

So my question is:

1. Is there a way to get the function that `kdeplot` is using for plotting the orange line?
2. Is there a way to have a better regression that is accurate and does not over/underfit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of the empirical CDF (ECDF) of a sample is very simple. First, the value of the ECDF below the minimum observation is $0$ and its value above the maximum observation is $1.$
Second, sort the data from smallest to largest. If there are $n$ observations (all distinct), then the ECDF jumps up by $1/n$ at each observation. If there are ties, the jump is $d/n$ for $d$ values tied at the same value.

In R, the expression `ecdf` does the work. (You might want to read the R documentation for `ecdf`.) For moderate and large sample sizes the ECDF is often a good approximation of the distribution of the population from which the data are randomly sampled (shown in red in the plots below).

Examples (in R):

```
set.seed(813)
x = runif(50, 0, 10);  plot(ecdf(x));  rug(x)
  curve(punif(x, 0, 10), add=T, col="red", n=10001)
```

[image]

```
set.seed(2019)
x = rpois(10, 3); plot(ecdf(x))
curve(ppois(x, 3), add=T, col="red", n = 10001)
```

[image]

```
set.seed(1066)
x = rexp(5000, 1/10);  plot(ecdf(x))
curve(pexp(x, 1/10), add-T, col="red")
```

[image]

*Note:* Q-Q plots (with theoretical and sample quantiles) often amount to ECDF plots with scales suitably distorted so that the
population CDF is a straight line.

---

**Addendum** per @whuber Comment:

For a small dataset from a gamma distribution, we begin by showing a histogram of the data along with the true density function (left) and an ECDF of the data along with the true CDF (right). For illustration, I chose a small sample so that there will be a clear distinction between exact curves (blue) and estimated ones (red).

```
set.seed(814)
x = rgamma(100, 10, .2)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(x, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.03))
  curve(dgamma(x, 10, .2), add=T, col="blue")
 plot(ecdf(x), pch=".")
  curve(pgamma(x, 10, .2), add=T, col="blue")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

If the true population distribution is not known, its density
function can be estimated by a kernel density estimator (KDE). We use the default KDE in R. The output is two vectors: x-values and
y-values for plotting. These vectors are summarized below, and the first six entries in each vector are shown.

```
density(x)

Call:
        density.default(x = x)

Data: x (100 obs.);     Bandwidth 'bw' = 5.494

       x                 y            
 Min.   :  2.599   Min.   :9.031e-06  
 1st Qu.: 32.251   1st Qu.:9.730e-04  
 Median : 61.902   Median :4.177e-03  
 Mean   : 61.902   Mean   :8.423e-03  
 3rd Qu.: 91.554   3rd Qu.:1.602e-02  
 Max.   :121.205   Max.   :2.527e-02  
head(density(x)$x)
[1] 2.599014 2.831120 3.063227 3.295333 3.527439 3.759546
head(density(x)$y)
[1] 9.030655e-06 1.029092e-05 1.171087e-05 1.327874e-05 1.500377e-05 1.701109e-05
```

The points in the x-vector are evenly spaced.
The points in the y-vector are scaled so that the curve enclosed by the KDE will be (almost exactly) 1. The KDE vectors can be used
to estimate the CDF. Plotting points are `x.k = ecdf(x)$x a`
and `y.k = cumsum(ecdf(x)$y)/sum(ecdf(x)$y)`. Here are plots of the histogram of `x` along with the KDE, and the ECDF along with the
CDF as estimated via the KDE.

```
x.k = density(x)$x
y.k = cumsum(density(x)$y)/sum(density(x)$y)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(x, prob=T)
  lines(density(x), col="red")
 plot(ecdf(x), pch=".")
  lines(x.k, y.k, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: I believe the question is (in a somewhat disguised way) inquiring about how the CDF based on a KDE is computed and plotted, rather than about plotting an ECDF.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks. I confess I sill don't understand exactly what OP is trying to do. But your interpretation seems reasonable. Perhaps the Addendum to my answer will help.

Comment: @NickCox: Thanks for fixing typos.